# Matrix inversion using Neumann Series giving funny loss function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

According to (steward,1998). A matrix **A**  which is invertible can be approximated by the formula ***A^{-1} = \sum^{inf}_{n=0} (I- A)^{n}***

I tried implementing an algorithm to approximate a simple matrix's inverse, the loss function showed funny results. please look at the code below. more info about the Neumann series can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM6brJrJYbM) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)

here is my code.

```
 A = np.array([[1,0,2],[3,1,-2],[-5,-1,9]])
class Neumann_inversion():
    def __init__(self,A,rank):
        self.A = A
        self.rank = rank
        self.eye = np.eye(len(A)) 
        self.loss = []
        self.loss2 =[]
        self.A_hat = np.zeros((3,3),dtype = float)
        #self.loss.append(np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(self.A)-self.A_hat))
    
    def approximate(self):
       # self.A_hat = None
        n = 0
        L = (self.eye-self.A)
        
        while n < self.rank:
            
            self.A_hat += np.linalg.matrix_power(L,n)
            loss = np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(self.A) - self.A_hat)
            self.loss.append(loss)
            n+= 1
            
        plt.plot(self.loss)
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.xlabel('rank')
        # ax.axis('scaled')
            
        return 
    
   
Matrix = Neumann_inversion(A,200)
Matrix.approximate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is valid only if $A^n$ tends to zero as $n$ increase. So your matrix must satisfy

```
np.all(np.abs(np.linalg.eigvals(A)) < 1)
```

Try

```py
Neumann_inversion(A/10, 200).approximate()
```

and you can take the loss seriously :)
[image: loss]

The origin of the formula has something to do with

(1-x) * (1 + x + x^2 + ... x^n) = (1 - x^(n+1))

If, and only if, all the eigenvalues of the matrix have magnitude less than 1 the term x^(n+1) will be close to zero, so the sum will be approximately the inverse of (1-x).

Comment: I think it's rather `(I-A)^n` that has to tend to zero as `n` increases, as specified in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#By_Neumann_series). Therefore I do not understand in general why the condition is on the eigenvalues of `A` and not `I-A`.

Comment: Because if a matrix tends to zero then, all of its eigenvalues do, bacause the eigenvalues of `(I - A)^n` are the n-th power of the eigenvalues of `(I-A)` it is sufficient and necessary to have `(I -A)` with eigenvalues of magnitude less than 1.

Comment: My point was rather on which matrix should tend to zero, you wrote `A^n` in your answer but `(I-A)^n` in your comment. I think it's rather `(I-A)^n` and that's why I don't understand the suggested fix of dividing `A` by 10.

Comment: If you want to compute the inverse of `A` the condition is on the eigenvalues `A` so that `I - A^n` to converge to `I`. If you have a matrix that don't satisfy that condition you can scale mutliply it by a scalar to make it suitable.